# выдает ошибку синтаксиса, хотя ее нет, что не так?

Tags: php, база-данных

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема?
хочу связаться с базой данных

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect( host:'localhost', user:'root', password:'', database:'crud' );
```

но выдает ошибку

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'

Comment: "выдает ошибку синтаксиса, хотя ее нет," --- Есть. Ещё как есть.

Comment: Где вы в PHP видели двоеточия? При каком действии?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: Синтаксис вообще неверный...

Comment: делаю по аналогии с видоса, там все работает, у мменя нет, двоеточия конечно смущают но подумал что ладно уж, работает ведь.

Comment: Что за IDE используется? Ты там различаешь где подсказки IDE, а где твой код?

Comment: @Dmitry в видосе это подсказки IDE

Comment: визуал студио код использую, он не ругается ни на что

Comment: @АлексейШиманский но справедливости ради стоит заметить что именованные аргументы уже есть в восьмерке, так что `host:` даже работало бы, а вот остальное уже нет.

Comment: @u_mulder подловили)) да, но тут всё очевидно, кмк

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: @АлексейШиманский помимо двоеточий синтаксис тоже неверный?

Comment: @Dmitry посмотрите в ссылке выше Процедурный стиль

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да да, посмотрел. Большое спасибо! в видосе пхп шторм, я вроде и смутился, но так как только начал изучать подумал что ок пишу так же, а если присмотреться то пхпшторм в сам деле подсказки выводит чуть более темым фоном. Спасибо!